# JSOUP - JSP Login: Blank cookie

Tags: java, jsp, cookies, authentication, jsoup

I've seen some answers about this, here in the Stackoverflow but none of them solved my problem...

I want to perform a login in a JSP page, using Jsoup. Below you can see my code. The problem is that the second request using post doesn't return any Cookie, so, my last request can't reach the page that is after the login.

I'm sure the data is correct ("acao", "num" and "senha")... I inspected the request after a login in chrome (developer tools > network tab > seen the form data content).

Any ideas of what can be happenning with the code?

```
public class Extrator {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Connection.Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("URL LOGIN JSP")
            .method(Connection.Method.GET)
            .execute();

        @SuppressWarnings("unused")
        Connection.Response login = Jsoup.connect("URL LOGIN JSP")
            .data("acao", "entrar")
            .data("num", "user")
            .data("senha", "password")
            .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
            .method(Method.POST)
            .execute();

        Map<String, String> cookies = login.cookies();

        Document page = Jsoup.connect("PAGE AFTER LOGIN")
            .cookies(cookies)
            .get();
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add the actual URL? It's hard to tell what happens without it...

Comment: Without the url it is not possible to give a definite answer. What you could try: monitor the login process with chrome dev tools and compare the request headers. It is usually sensible to set the user agent. Also compare the cookies.

Comment: For "PAGE AFTER LOGIN" you only use the response cookies from "URL LOGIN JSP". Can you verify that these are the only cookies send in the request for "PAGE AFTER LOGIN"? There might be cookies needed from `loginForm`.

Comment: Sorry guys, the URL Login is: http://sac.desktop.com.br/Cliente_Login.jsp

Comment: @FredericKlein I didn't get what you said with: "There might be cookies needed from loginForm". How so?

Comment: I also tried to set the user agent... Didn't work too..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Problem**

The response from your form submission (`login`) doesn't contain the cookie with the `JSESSIONID`, so for the last request, you are not sending any cookies to the page.

**Solution**

Use the cookies with the `JSESSIONID` from `loginForm`:

```
try {
    Response loginForm = Jsoup.connect("http://sac.desktop.com.br/Cliente_Login.jsp")
        .method(Method.GET)
        .execute();

    Response login = Jsoup.connect("http://sac.desktop.com.br/Cliente_Menu.jsp")
        .data("acao", "entrar")
        .data("num", "user")
        .data("senha", "password")
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .method(Method.POST)
        .execute();

    Document page = Jsoup.connect("http://sac.desktop.com.br/Cliente_Menu.jsp")
        .cookies(loginForm.cookies())
        .get();

    System.out.println(page.html());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Worked perfectly. Thank you Frederic!